Using one distance metric on another distance matrix
In general, is it correct to use one distance metric on another distance matrix? For example, is it valid to use Euclidean metric on Jaccard distance matrix as input data in algorithms? or any other measure? if yes/no, why?
For more details on why I am asking, check out this topic on DS.SE.

Could you elaborate on what you mean by "correct" and in what context?  From a pragmatic perspective, literally anything you can do to identify or characterize a pattern in data can be useful.

From a pragmatic perspective, yes, I have a similar view. But I want to be sure that at some stage of the calculations there will be no undesirable effects of using one length on the other.
In my case it's euclidean distance (within UMAP dim reduction) use on jaccard matrix as input data.(see  hyperlink within question)
Specifically, if limitations of euclidean distance will interfere here.

You would need to explain more specifically in this post what "use one length on the other" might mean.

I feel like i already did specifically described my question. It is in my comment above as well as in linked DS.SE question.
This topic is to get general broader look on use case's of one similarity/dissimilarity matrix as an input data in algorithms/methodologies using other distance measures within it's computation steps.
What should be one aware of and when to and when better not to apply such solution.

The reason I specified "in this post" is that we (strongly) prefer questions to stand on their own without requiring readers to research other materials just to understand the question.
